# How to create buttons of diffrent sizes in a toolbar control (Win32 API)

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to insert buttons of diffrent sizes in a toolbar.
Lets say for example 2 buttons. One have a size of 32x16, the Other 16x16.
I used Two Image Lists. Each image list has it's own image size (1st 32x16 - 2nd 16x16).
But the problem is, when I compile the code i get the images loaded correctly but the buttons have the same width(32).

code:

```
//(1) Create the Toolbar ImageList
HIMAGELIST hImageListLarge = ImageList_Create(32, 16, ILC_COLOR8 | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);
if (!hImageListLarge)
    return false;

HIMAGELIST hImageListSmall = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR8 | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);
if (!hImageListSmall)
    return false;

//(2) Fill the Image List
if (ImageList_Add(hImageListLarge,
    LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_CONNECT_TO)),
    LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_CONNECT_TO_MASK))) == -1)
    return false;

if (ImageList_Add(hImageListSmall,
    LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_HELP)),
    LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_HELP_MASK))) == -1)
    return false;



//(3) Create the Toolbar window
m_hToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, nullptr,
    WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE | TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE | TBSTYLE_LIST | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS ,
    0, 0, 0, 0, m_hWnd, nullptr, m_hInstance, nullptr);

if (m_hToolbar == nullptr)
    return false;

//(4) Sets the Image list for the Toolbar
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, CCM_SETVERSION, 5, 0);
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM)hImageListLarge);
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 1, (LPARAM)hImageListSmall);

//(5) Initialize the TBBUTTON structures for each button
m_tbButtons[0].fsStyle = BTNS_SEP;

m_tbButtons[1].iBitmap = MAKELONG(0, 0);
m_tbButtons[1].idCommand = ID_CONNECTIONS_CONNECT_TO;
m_tbButtons[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
m_tbButtons[1].fsStyle = BTNS_BUTTON | BTNS_AUTOSIZE;
m_tbButtons[1].iString = (INT_PTR)TEXT("Connect to");

m_tbButtons[2].iBitmap = MAKELONG(0, 1);
m_tbButtons[2].idCommand = ID_HELP_ABOUT;
m_tbButtons[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
m_tbButtons[2].fsStyle = BTNS_BUTTON | BTNS_AUTOSIZE ;
m_tbButtons[2].iString = (INT_PTR)TEXT("Help");


//(6) Add buttons to the toolbar 
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, 3, (LPARAM)m_tbButtons);

//(7) auto Resize the toolbar
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS);
ShowWindow(m_hToolbar, SW_SHOW);

//(8) Modify the size of the separator that will hold the combobox
TBBUTTONINFO tbbi;
tbbi.cbSize = sizeof(tbbi);
tbbi.dwMask = TBIF_SIZE | TBIF_BYINDEX;
tbbi.cx = 500;
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)& tbbi);

tbbi.cx = 32;
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)1, (LPARAM)& tbbi);

tbbi.cx = 16;
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)2, (LPARAM)& tbbi);




//(9) Get the Rectangle occupied by the separator
RECT rcSep;
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_GETITEMRECT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)& rcSep);

//(10) Create the hosts comboBox
m_hComboHosts = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE,
    rcSep.left, rcSep.top, rcSep.right - rcSep.left, rcSep.bottom - rcSep.top, m_hToolbar,
    (HMENU)IDC_COMBO_HOSTS, m_hInstance, nullptr);

if (!m_hComboHosts)
    return false;

return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick check, please modify the following code:

Comment this line of code：

```
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS);
```

> **TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS**
>
> Version 5.81. This style allows you to set text for all buttons, but
>   only display it for those buttons with the BTNS_SHOWTEXT button style.
>   The TBSTYLE_LIST style must also be set. Normally, when a button does
>   not display text, your application must handle TBN_GETINFOTIP or
>   TTN_GETDISPINFO to display a tooltip. With the TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS
>   extended style, text that is set but not displayed on a button will
>   automatically be used as the button's tooltip text. Your application
>   only needs to handle TBN_GETINFOTIP or or TTN_GETDISPINFO if it needs
>   more flexibility in specifying the tooltip text.

When you set `TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS` style, it will allow you to set text for all buttons.

After testing, this style will prevent you from changing the width of the button.

If you want to display the button text, just add the `BTNS_SHOWTEXT` style.

Modified code:

```
//(1) Create the Toolbar ImageList
    HIMAGELIST hImageListLarge = ImageList_Create(32, 16, ILC_COLOR8 | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);
    if (!hImageListLarge)
        return false;

    HIMAGELIST hImageListSmall = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR8 | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);
    if (!hImageListSmall)
        return false;

    //(2) Fill the Image List
    if (ImageList_Add(hImageListLarge,
        LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_CONNECT_TO)),
        LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_CONNECT_TO_MASK))) == -1)
        return false;

    if (ImageList_Add(hImageListSmall,
        LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_HELP)),
        LoadBitmap(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TB_HELP_MASK))) == -1)
        return false;



    //(3) Create the Toolbar window
    m_hToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, nullptr,
        WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE | TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE | TBSTYLE_LIST | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, m_hWnd, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);

    if (m_hToolbar == nullptr)
        return false;

    //(4) Sets the Image list for the Toolbar
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, CCM_SETVERSION, 5, 0);
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM)hImageListLarge);
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 1, (LPARAM)hImageListSmall);

    //(5) Initialize the TBBUTTON structures for each button


    m_tbButtons[0].fsStyle = BTNS_SEP;

    m_tbButtons[1].iBitmap = MAKELONG(0, 0);
    m_tbButtons[1].idCommand = ID_CONNECTIONS_CONNECT_TO;
    m_tbButtons[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    m_tbButtons[1].fsStyle = BTNS_BUTTON | BTNS_AUTOSIZE; // If you want display text, you can add BTNS_SHOWTEXT 
    m_tbButtons[1].iString = (INT_PTR)TEXT("Connect to");

    m_tbButtons[2].iBitmap = MAKELONG(0, 1);
    m_tbButtons[2].idCommand = ID_HELP_ABOUT;
    m_tbButtons[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    m_tbButtons[2].fsStyle = BTNS_BUTTON | BTNS_AUTOSIZE;
    m_tbButtons[2].iString = (INT_PTR)TEXT("Help");


    //(6) Add buttons to the toolbar 
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, 3, (LPARAM)m_tbButtons);

    //(7) auto Resize the toolbar
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    //SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, 0, (LPARAM)TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS);
    ShowWindow(m_hToolbar, SW_SHOW);

    //(8) Modify the size of the separator that will hold the combobox
    TBBUTTONINFO tbbi;
    tbbi.cbSize = sizeof(tbbi);
    tbbi.dwMask = TBIF_SIZE | TBIF_BYINDEX;
    tbbi.cx = 44;
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)1, (LPARAM)& tbbi);

    tbbi.cx = 27;
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)2, (LPARAM)& tbbi);


    //(9) Get the Rectangle occupied by the separator
    RECT rcSep;
    SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_GETITEMRECT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)& rcSep);

    //(10) Create the hosts comboBox
    m_hComboHosts = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE,
        rcSep.left, rcSep.top, rcSep.right - rcSep.left, rcSep.bottom - rcSep.top, m_hToolbar,
        (HMENU)IDC_COMBO_HOSTS, hInst, nullptr);

    if (!m_hComboHosts)
        return false;

return true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me. When i removed the TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS extended style the buttons had different widths. But the Tooltips were not displaying!! I tried to use the solutions given in the microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/display-tooltips-for-buttons but this is not working!!

Answer (score 0):

I used the first TB_SETBUTTONINFO message to modify the size of a button (Separator). 
To make it large enough for holding a comboBox control:

```
//(8) Modify the size of the separator that will hold the combobox
TBBUTTONINFO tbbi;
tbbi.cbSize = sizeof(tbbi);
tbbi.dwMask = TBIF_SIZE | TBIF_BYINDEX;
tbbi.cx = 500;
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)& tbbi);
```

This is the code for creating the ComboBox:

```
//(9) Get the Rectangle occupied by the separator
RECT rcSep;
SendMessage(m_hToolbar, TB_GETITEMRECT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)& rcSep);

//(10) Create the hosts comboBox
m_hComboHosts = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOXW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE,
    rcSep.left, rcSep.top, rcSep.right - rcSep.left, rcSep.bottom - rcSep.top, m_hToolbar,
    (HMENU)IDC_COMBO_HOSTS, m_hInstance, nullptr);
```

This is working as expected.

But when I try to add two other buttons (32x16 - 16x16), I get always the same width of the first Imagelist (32).

But when I swap the image list indexes, I get (16 for both).

I am using the new Visual styles ComCtl32.lib

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been posted as an edit to your question instead.

Comment: You didn't set the width of the second button. See my answer update.